# OpenCV: PNP pose estimation fails in a specific case

Tags: opencv, pose-estimation

I am using OpenCV's solvePnPRansac function to estimate the pose of my camera given a pointcloud made from tracked features. My pipeline consists of multiple cameras where I form the point cloud from matched features between two cameras, and use that as a reference to estimate the pose of one of the cameras as it starts moving. I have tested this in multiple settings and it works as long as there are enough features to track while the camera is in motion.

Strangely, during a test I did today, I encountered a failure case where solvePnP would just return junk values all the time. What's confusing here is that in this data set, my point cloud is much denser, it's reconstructed pretty accurately from the two views, the tracked number of points (currently visible features vs. features in the point cloud) at any given time was much higher than what I usually have, so theoretically it should have been a breeze for solvePnP, yet it fails terribly.

I tried with CV_ITERATIVE, CV_EPNP and even the non RANSAC version of solvePnP. I was just wondering if I am missing something basic here? The scene I am looking at can be seen in these images (image 1 is the scene and feature matches between two perspectives, image 2 is the point cloud for reference)

[image: Feature matches]

[image: Point cloud]

The part of the code doing PNP is pretty simple. If P3D is the array of tracked 3Dpoints, P2D is the corresponding set of image points,

```
solvePnpRansac(P3D, P2D, K, d, R, T, false, 500, 2.0, 100, noArray(), CV_ITERATIVE);
```

EDIT: I should also mention that my reference poincloud was obtained with a baseline of 8 feet between the cameras, whereas the building I am looking at was probably like a 100 feet away. Could the possible lack of disparity cause issues as well?